# Find previous sunday date algorithm

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, date

I found a couple examples online but I don't quite understand how it works. e.g

```
     SELECT DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,GETDATE()), 0)
```

I'm not even sure it does what I want.

What I need is, when the query is executed, it can `SELECT * from xTable WHERE xDate` is between two dates. Last sunday and next sunday (current week). What could I use to find it automaticly? And please explain because I'm new to SQL.

Comment: I don't understand why someone could vote for closing as _"not a real question"_. It's clear what OP wants to know: how to get current week's records. But the question is, have you tried the query and it returned the wrong result?

Comment: It actually returns a date I can't quite find how to use this query to get to my result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked deeper in trying to understand this query

```
 SELECT DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,GETDATE()), 0)
```

And used it to retreive the previous monday. Now I can simply `DATEADD` 6 more days to get a full week.

The solution I used :

```
       Set @Monday =  DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,GETDATE()), 0)
       Set @Sunday =  DATEADD(dd, 06, @Monday)
```

Problem solved.

Comment: If you don't have future dates in your table, this is the most efficient way: `SELECT * from xTable 
    WHERE xDate >=  DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,GETDATE()), 0)`. If you also want to restrict the future dates (more than one week): `SELECT * from xTable 
    WHERE xDate >=  DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,GETDATE()), 0) AND xDate < DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,GETDATE()), 7)`

Comment: Its for a report actually forgot to mention. So if someone wants to reprint a report from two months ago there will be some future dates im afraid. But I tried it and it works perfectly if it's not for the future dates problem. Thanks:)